# Need to format JSON output in order to be compatible with my backend service

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON output from a form like this

```
{
  "testRefs": {
    "testCd": null,
    "testIndicator": null,
    "testInd": null,
    "testiolInd": null
  },
  "testList": {
    "testname": null,
    "testcode": null
  },
 "testCd": "someStrinf",
      "testNm": "someString"
}
```

I need to format the form output to

```
{
  "testRefs": [
    {
      "testCd": null,
      "testIndicator": null,
      "testInd": null,
      "testiolInd": null
    }],
    {
      "testList": [
        {
          "testname": null,
          "testcode": null
        }
      ],
      "testCd": "someStrinf",
      "testNm": "someString"
    }
  ]
}
```

to be compatible with backend service

How do i add array signs

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**for..in**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) and check the length of keys at `obj[key]` if it's greater than 1 just add it in an array else keep it unchanged.

```js
let obj = { "testRefs": { "testCd": null,"testIndicator": null,"testInd": null,"testiolInd": null},"testList": {"testname": null,"testcode": null},"testCd": null,"testNm": null}

for(let key in obj){
  if(Object.keys(obj[key]||[]).length > 1){
    obj[key] = [obj[key]]
  }
}

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: If a string is passed at "testCd" / "testNm" they get added as array too. I've edited my question as per this problem